Many requests within short space crashing Node.js server
I am running a Node.js (v22) application on docker with a Vue 3 front-end. The application works fine except it has crashed randomly which I cannot work out why it happens. I had a look at the docker log for the container and I can see that it basically starts timing out after this:
{"log":"onServerPrefetch ran getProduct(14425)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-06-19T16:46:29.289530937Z"}
{"log":"onServerPrefetch ran getProduct(14430)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-06-19T16:46:29.303259316Z"}
{"log":"onServerPrefetch ran getProduct(14427)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-06-19T16:46:29.315447855Z"}
{"log":"onServerPrefetch ran getProduct(14417)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-06-19T16:46:29.32901105Z"}
{"log":"onServerPrefetch ran getProduct(14419)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-06-19T16:46:29.346483497Z"}
{"log":"onServerPrefetch ran getProduct(14433)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-06-19T16:46:29.370365608Z"}
{"log":"onServerPrefetch ran getProduct(14424)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-06-19T16:46:29.382479396Z"}
{"log":"onServerPrefetch ran getProduct(14417)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-06-19T16:46:29.395289652Z"}
{"log":"onServerPrefetch ran getProduct(13182)\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-06-19T16:46:29.477117327Z"}

The above log means that Vue's onServerPrefetch() ran which allows the server to render a page and serve it to the browser (server-side rendering). It is served via Express.
After the above has occured I get the following error from the console.error log:
{"log":"ProductView.vue error: AxiosError: timeout of 120000ms exceeded\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-06-19T16:48:29.311004059Z"}

So when someone or something has made multiple different requests to view Products on the application, it causes a crash of some kind. I am not sure what has crashed exactly but Axios no longer gets any data from the API running on the same Node server.
Is there any global setting I can enable to limit how many requests can be made in a second to the server to see if that is the problem or does anyone know what the might problem might be?

There's a big assumption here its the volume of requests. Its far more likely IMO that this is an application layer bug. That's a trivial amount of requests, so likely you have some async locking/race condition issue in the application code. Does it actually crash or just stop responding? Does the process die?

@adsy It doesn't crash, it stops responding. Like no more data on the site at all.

Then its more than likely a problem in the application layer. Its locking, and you can't solve this at the dev ops level. You need to use a debugger and repro it. That its linked to simultaneous requests is just because that increases the chance of hitting the locking condition. Its most likely not a "load" issue at all. Unless we're talking crazy numbers of reqs.

@adsy thank you for the help, I am on my own so no team to go to. I am not sure how to debug it because it happens randomly. Like the application can go for a whole day or more and then suddenly there's no data on the site.

So what I would do is run node with the inspect flag. See https://nodejs.org/en/learn/getting-started/debugging. Then when it gets into this state, you will be able to remotely attach a debugger and see the state of all the threads and where they are trapped. Another option is trying to repro it locally by hitting the API endpoint that triggers it a lot. Also under debug.

Also check for patterns. For example, when it happens, did it always access the same product id last? What does onServerPrefetch do for this component? What does getProduct() do? What are the implementations of these?
